# How can I read a CSV file I downloaded from MemoryStream using C# .net?

Tags: c#, .net, csv, memorystream

I'm downloading a file, supposedly a .csv file, from an external URL with the following code.

```
MemoryStream download = new MemoryStream(client.DownloadData(targetUrl));
```

In the download variable theres data being populated but my problem now is actually reading that data. I tried the following:

```
StreamReader dataReader = new StreamReader(download, 
                                           System.Text.Encoding.Default, 
                                           true);
```

This and all other Encoding types are tried only return gibberish instead of the .csv data I need. Can anybody tell me how to do it?

Comment: What encoding is the CSV file in?

Comment: That's just the thing, I don't know, and I've tried them all and they're still giving me gibberish.

Comment: Then you need to contact the provider of the CSV and ask them.

Comment: I am going to delete this question since I found out that the file I'm getting through the download is not even in the right format and my problem is found elsewhere. Thanks to everyone that tried to help me.

Comment: Don't delete it - the answers may be useful to someone in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading the file data with the default system code page (`Encoding.Default`) - it appears that the file is **not** in that encoding.

You **must** use the encoding that the file is encoded with in order to read it successfully.

I suggest trying Unicode (UTF16), UTF8 and ASCII encodings as probable options. If none of these work as expected (that is, gibberish is produced), you need to find out the original encoding.

```
StreamReader dataReader = new StreamReader(download, 
                                           System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, 
                                           true);
```

Comment: Encoding.Default is never utf-16, that's Encoding.Unicode.  Default is the default system code page.  Like 1252 on your machine, the default Windows code page on machines in Western Europe.  Try Encoding.Default.CodePage to see.

Comment: @HansPassant - Thanks for the correction. I was indeed thinking about `Encoding.Unicode`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org) to find out which encoding is being used.